What's the meaning of the following C++ code?
Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the following C++ code, please? Better translate this to C# so that I can understand it more clearly.
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
static std::string Join(const T& delim, const Args& ...args)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    bool first = true;

    auto tmp = { ((first ? oss : oss << delim) << args, first = false)... };
    [&tmp]() { };

    return std::move(oss.str());
}

An example of its usage is like
Join("something", "\"", "\"");

I wonder what it will produce.

It is a C++ equivalent of the C# String.Join(String, Objectt]) method. It concats a list of values separated by delim, and the values can be any streamable type.

Thank you @RemyLebeau! I really appreciate your answer, though I still don't under the statement { ((first ? oss : oss << delim) << args, first = false)... }. And, is [&tmp]() { }; just a definition without execution?

[&tmp]() { }; is a lambda expression.  Since it is not assigned to anything its a do nothing operation.  Not sure where you found this function but its not great code.

No you cannot translate C++ to C# just like that (different semantics). What you see is a variadic function template (that has no direct equivalent in C#, even if it looks similare to C#'s generics). A template is something that is "expanded" at compile time. Within the function you can also find a fold expression, again a compile time construct to basically write a bit of code for each template argument (again something with no equivalent in C#). So to really understand this you really need to study some C++ (and forget about C#)

A better example usage might be std::string csv = Join(",", "answer", 42, "pi", 3.14);

ChatGPT is particularly good at explaining written code.

Your question could be improved if you called out specific syntax you don't understand (especially in the title)  For example, "What does the ... do and what purpose does the empty lambda serve?"

@Sinatr Not really: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79116340/how-many-bytes-are-initialised

Before the downvoting avalanche sweeps this away, I'd appreciate knowing what's killing this question.  The answer is excellent and fairly addresses the intent of the question.  I assume it's the "please translate this to C# so I can understand it" (which is odd; probably better to just explain it) and the poor open-ended wording "what is the meaning of..."?  Otherwise, I think it's fair to ask how the code works.  Downvoters should suggest ways to improve the question given the high quality of the answer.

[&tmp]() { }; is a strange way to silent unused variable warning, attribute [[maybe_unused]] (C++17) or casting to void is more idiomatic.

This code is a C++ equivalent of the C# String.Join(String, Object[]) method. It concats a list of values separated by delim, and the values can be any streamable type.
This function is a variadic template. The args function parameter can be passed any number of values. The compiler will deduce the Args template argument to be the types of all the parameters passed in by the caller, and the args function parameter will receive their values.
oss is an output stream that appends outputted values to an internal std::string.
tmp is a compiler-deduced type whose initialization is utilizing a pack expansion pattern to iterate the values in args, applying the pattern ((first ? oss : oss << delim) << args, first = false) to each value of args.
The following (uncalled) lambda likely just ensures that tmp is not optimized away as an unused object (thus avoiding the initialization), and to prevent the compiler from warning that the object is unused.
(first ? oss : oss << delim) is a conditional operator expression (sometimes also referred to as the ternary operator) in the form:

E1 ? E2 : E3

If E1 (first) evaluates as true then the result is E2 (oss) otherwise E3 (oss << delim).
On the first iteration of the pack expansion, first is true, so
the conditional expression yields (a reference to) oss itself. On subsequent iterations, first is false, so the expression yields the result of oss << delim, which returns a reference to oss.
Every iteration of the expansion performs oss << args to output the current iteration's value of args, and to set first to false.
So, effectively, the 1st value of args is output, then delim, then the 2nd value of args, then delim, and so on.
Then the final std::string stored in oss is returned. oss.str() returns a temporary std::string by value that is a copy of the stream's content. The Join function also returns a std::string by value, which the author might have thought would cause another copy to be made,  so the author chose to use std::move() to explicitly allow the compiler to "steal" the 1st string's content without copying it again. But this is not actually needed as the compiler would have done that anyway due to copy elision, so the std::move() is redundant in this case.

Is [&tmp]() { }; really needed to ensure tmp is not optimized away (given that its initialization causes an obsevable side effect on oss which is returned) ?

@wohlstad Now that I think about it more it was probably used to avoid an unused variable warning

Would the best way to return the string be std::move(oss).str(), calling overload (3) here? Both oss.str() and std::move(oss.str()) seem to involve a copy.

@RemyLebeau Correct me if I'm wrong: oss.str() copies the internal string of oss since oss is an lvalue, and copy elision will just elide the move of the already copied string.

Note that I don't think there's any fold expression in the OP's code.  Instead the comma separated elements of the list tmp are generated by a simple parameter pack expansion, right?

@G.M. you are right, it is a simple pack expansion, not a fold expression. I have corrected it.
